# twig template engine function or filter to ceil a number

Tags: symfony, twig

Is there a twig template engine's equivalent function or filter of PHP's [ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function. I looked in the documentation but couldn't find a ready made filter or function.

Comment: I don't think your answer is mathematically sound. Consider: {{ 20 // 4 + 1 }} This code would yield 6, but the result should be 5 since 20 is already divisible by 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Maybe you could try using the // operator, like this:</s>

```
{{20 // 1 + 1}}
```

If this is not short enough for you, then you should probably [write your own twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: This is not equivalent to `ceil`.

Answer (score 1):

Twig has recently added this feature:

```
{{ (3.333)|round(0, 'ceil') }}
```

Check out the documentation [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/round.html)